# onItemSelected is not invoked in Spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

I tried to implement a Spinner in my application. Everything is displayed correctly, the spinner is also succesfully populated with the Items.

My Problem:
When I select an Item, nothing happens.

Here is my Code in the onCreate:

```
Spinner spinner;

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, eventTitles);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Log.d("Spinner",adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                Toast.makeText(AdminActivity.this, "Hello Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                Log.d("Spinner","Nothing selected!");

            }
        });
```

Any Advice?

Thanks! 
Alex

Comment: Set the `DropDownViewResource` on the spinner not the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I messed up something in my AsyncTask. Now it works! Thank you all for you answers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you have already defined layout for spinner in adapter again it is not required and use OnItemSelectedListener instead of using  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.

Try this,

```
 Spinner spinner;

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, eventTitles);
            spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Log.d("Spinner",adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                    Toast.makeText(AdminActivity.this, "Hello Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    Log.d("Spinner","Nothing selected!");

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the doc, `Spinner` doesn't support item click events. To react to user clicks, call the `setOnItemClickListener` of your `ArrayAdapter` object instead.